# How to run postmapping in a RestController in Springboot

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I am very new to Springboot and do not fully understand how postmapping works. Currently, I have to implement Stripe payment system. From what I gathered, Stripe provides a custom payment flow but it is using Spark framework. I was able to create a Springboot Postmapping in place of the Spark Post. I have tried different methods I see online with no success. What would be the best method to do the following.

My PostMapping Code

```
@PostMapping("/create-payment-intent")
public String StripeTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws StripeException {
    System.out.println("Stripe Controller Begins");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_key";

    try {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String dataBody = buffer.toString();

        CreatePayment postBody = gson.fromJson(dataBody,
                CreatePayment.class);

        PaymentIntentCreateParams createParams = new PaymentIntentCreateParams.Builder()
                .setCurrency("USD")
                .setAmount(new Long(calculateOrderAmount(postBody.getItems())))
                .build();
        // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
        PaymentIntent intent = PaymentIntent.create(createParams);
        // Send publishable key and PaymentIntent  details to client
        return gson.toJson(new Server.CreatePaymentResponse(intent.getClientSecret()));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

I need to get the post to run then fetch the data using my javascript:

```
// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
    const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
    });
    const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

    const appearance = {
        theme: 'stripe',
    };
    elements = stripe.elements({ appearance, clientSecret });

    const paymentElementOptions = {
        layout: "tabs",
    };

    const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", paymentElementOptions);
    paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}
```

Which will then be injected into the payment-id in the html below:

```
<form id="payment-form"         action='/create-payment-intent' method='POST'>
  <div id="payment-element">
    <!--Stripe.js injects the Payment Element-->
  </div>
  <button id="submit">
    <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
    <span id="button-text">Pay now</span>
  </button>
  <div id="payment-message" class="hidden"></div>
</form>
```

I have tried $.Ajax from an example I read with no luck.

Comment: How are you running the springboot service? How are you running the javascript? Is the endpoint reachable by the javascript?
What kind of failures are  you experiencing?

Comment: The springboot application is running locally. The javascript is executed using the following in the html page: <script src="/js/stripe/checkout.js" defer></script>. It seems the postmapping isnt working as it is only displaying the button "Pay Now". It displays correctly using Spark since it displays the input for credit cards and the button.